# HTML Background color not filling whole page?

Tags: html, css

Hey everyone here's a picture of the problem:

[image]

I want it to fill the the whitespace on the left right and top of the green box.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>Test page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" name="header">
        <h1>Blegh</h1>
            <style>
                #container {font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;}
            </style>
     </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    background-color: #58FA58;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Remove the default padding and margins on the elements.

Comment: Unrelated: `<style>` elements are not allowed in `<body>` unless scoped.

Comment: @j08691 How would i do that?

Comment: Put your <style> elements on <head>, and try to add on your CSS : *{ margin:0; padding:0}

Comment: If you want to cover the whole page with the background color, you need to apply the style to something that covers the whole page, like the body tag.

Comment: You should examine your question and decide whether you are trying to 'fill the page' or just reach the edges side to side. There is a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two rules should do it:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
h1 {
    margin:0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/cbezu4oe/)**

Comment: Will mark as answer in 8 minutes, Thank you! Also how do i raise the green box to the top of the page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by raising the green box to the top of the page. In the fiddle example it's already at the top.

Comment: The actual question seems to be about getting the color to 'Fill the page'. This does not address that.

Comment: @drummin - "I want it to fill the the whitespace on the left right and top of the green box."

Comment: And the question at the top says "HTML Background color not filling whole page?"

Comment: @drummin - So edit it, or ask for clarification. Downvoting my answer doesn't seem to make sense, especially when the OP says they'll accept it.

Comment: I asked them to re-evaluate the question.

Answer (score 4):

that's because of browsers. default of browsers has margin and padding and you should set padding and margin to zero  in all of your projects

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you set div heigt to 100 px :)

to make div like boddy wraper you shlud have this CSS

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#container{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -20px;
}

.footer, .push {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the body margins. Add this to your css:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your style.css:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying a margin and padding of 0 will allow all of your elements to reach the borders of the page. But if you want the color to fill the entire page, which seems to be the actual question, apply your background-color to the body tag.

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #58FA58;
}
```